# Multitenancy: Spring Vs Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-security, oauth-2.0, saas, multi-tenant

I am exploring out the concept of multitenancy in J2EE world. 
From what I understand multitenancy can be shared Web/App server, shared Database, shared OS or shared Physical Server.

Am I right if I say Spring Framework (esp Spring Security 3.2 ?), takes care of the multitenancy in Web/App Server level and Hibernate 4.0 takes care of it in DB level, and that the multitenancy feature provided by them work independent of each other.
i.e if I dont need multitenancy in one tier (say database tier, meaning shared database), I can live happily with only Spring security multitenancy feature at app server tier?

We are basically going to start developing brand new project

FronEnd: AngularJS
Backend: SpringMVC Restful
ORM: Hibernate 4
DB: MySQL (We dont have lot of money for Oracle etc :))

Given this toolkit, are there any good books, reference materials or github project that would give us a right direction on Multitenancy (and also Oauth)?

Thank you!

PS: I am exploring various bits an pieces online as I write.

Answer (score 1):

**Multitenancy :-** The term multi-tenancy in general is applied to software development to indicate an architecture in which a single running instance of an application simultaneously serves multiple clients (tenants). This is highly common in SaaS solutions. Isolating information (data, customizations, etc) pertaining to the various tenants is a particular challenge in these systems. This includes the data owned by each tenant stored in the database. It is this last piece, sometimes called multi-tenant data, on which we will focus.

Hibernate 4 Support : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

It isn't difficult to configure Multitenancy in hibernate 4, you don't need oracle. There could be different approaches.

**Multi-tenant data approaches:-**

1. Separate database
2. Separate schema
3. Partitioned (discriminator) data

**Description :-**
  For Earlier versions of hibernate you can extend `BasicDataSource` and come up with your own connection url logic depending upon your implementation.

Comment: Thank you Jaffar, this doesn't answer my questions completely though. 1. I also want to understand multitenancy from springs perspective. If I am writing a brand new web app (Spring + Hibernate) with multitenancy feature, should I be first developing a POC from Springs perspective, or hibernate perspective? 2. What if I don't need a shared database, but a shared app/web server?

Comment: I want to implement DISCRIMINATOR based (single table-shared schema model) multi-tenancy using Hibernate? Is it possible?

Comment: @Ketan from hibernate docs.. " DISCRIMINATOR Correlates to the partitioned (discriminator) approach. It is an error to attempt to open a session without a tenant identifier using this strategy. This strategy is not yet implemented in Hibernate as of 4.0 and 4.1. Its support is planned for 5.0."